# How to properly source/use lua file in `init.vim` config for neovim?

Tags: lua, neovim

I am new to neovim and I discovered that configs can be written in lua. I have been using `init.vim`(located at `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`), but I wanted to start writing new configs in lua. What is the standard way(or best practices) for sourcing/using lua files in my `init.vim` ?

At the moment, I have gotten lua running in `init.vim` script by enclosing lua script between `lua <<EOF` and `EOF` tags. However, I don't get any syntax highlighting in vim for my lua code when I do this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're just starting out, instead of `init.vim` you can place your configuration in `.config/nvim/init.lua`. E.g. instead of this in `init.vim`:

```
set nocompatible
set number
set cmdheight=2
```

You might have this in `init.lua`:

```
-- This is just a shortcut that allows us to use `o` as an alias for `vim.opt`
local o = vim.opt

o.comatible = false
o.number = true
o.cmdheight = 2
```

---

If you have an existing `init.vim` and you don't want to immediately convert everything into lua, you can add to your `init.vim`:

```
lua require('init')
```

And this will load the file `.config/nvim/lua/init.lua`.

Comment: One caveat: ensure to put `lua require('init')` at the end of `init.vim` if you intend to load packages that you installed in `init.vim`.